# Maven changes-Plugin can't generate jira-report

Tags: rest, maven, jira

I'm trying to get releasenotes through `Jira` with the help of the [Maven changes-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/). My pom looks something like this:

```
<issueManagement>
    <system>Jira</system>
    <url>https://url_to_jira</url>
</issueManagement>

<reporting>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <fixVersionIds>14876</fixVersionIds>
            <jiraUser>myUser</jiraUser>
            <jiraPassword>myPassword</jiraPassword>
            <webUser>myUser</webUser>
            <webPassword>myPassword</webPassword>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
```

I then call `mvn changes:jira-report` which generates an empty html-page for me. It always warns me that

```
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin.
[WARNING]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not find status Closed.
```

Which doesn't really help. Running `mvn` with `-X` shows me, that for some reason the request-header has no authentication part.

```
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: https://url_to_jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo
Http-Method: GET
Content-Type: */*
Headers: {Accept=[application/json], Content-Type=[*/*]}
--------------------------------------
Feb 25, 2014 12:51:00 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInIn
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, no-transform], con
Payload: {stuff}
--------------------------------------
Feb 25, 2014 12:51:00 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutI
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 2
Address: https://url_to_jira/rest/api/2/status
Http-Method: GET
Content-Type: */*
Headers: {Accept=[application/json], Content-Type=[*/*]}
--------------------------------------
Feb 25, 2014 12:51:00 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInIn
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 2
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {//somestuff//, X-AUSERNAME=[anonymous]}
Payload: []
--------------------------------------
```

Mind the `X-AUSERNAME=[anonymous]`-part.

So there it tries to get a list of the status and gets an empty list instead, because it doesn't even try to authenticate itself with `Jira`, which is odd, since I provided a `webUser` and a `jiraUser` with passwords inside my pom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could answer your question:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/examples/customizing-jira-report.html

> Starting with JIRA 5.1 it is no longer possible to ask JIRA questions using query parameters. If you use JIRA 5.1 or newer you must add this configuration[...]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your installation of JIRA uses custom status IDs.

I find the solution. You should go to the link below to get `resolution` and `status`:

```
http://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/resolution/
http://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/status/
```

and then use the `id` or `name` from above result to config `resolutionIds` and `statusIds`:

```
  <issueManagement>
    <system>JIRA</system>
    <url>http://jira.xxx.com/browse/PROJ_NAME</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <useJql>true</useJql>
          <jiraUser>username</jiraUser>
          <jiraPassword>password</jiraPassword>
          <!-- 
              <onlyCurrentVersion>true</onlyCurrentVersion>
           -->
              <!-- http://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/resolution/ -->
              <!-- http://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/status/ -->
              <resolutionIds>10010</resolutionIds>
              <statusIds>10011</statusIds>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
            <!-- 
              <report>changes-report</report>
             -->
              <report>jira-report</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

You can change the settings as admin under `management` -> `issues` -> `issue properties` -> `statuses` or `resolutions` menu.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/jira-report-mojo.html#statusIds